# How can I do unity GPGPU on Android device?

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, gpu, gpgpu

I wanna use GPU to compute Matrix multiplication in Unity platform

Someone commanded 'Compute shader', but I cannot use it because my application run on Android device.(I heard that Compute shader cannot be run on Android since it is based on DirectX)

Also, in my application, computation code must be in Unity C#, not Android.

How can I solve this problem? Is there any tool for this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because there are many different GPUs with varying instruction sets across hundreds of Android devices, programming direct to the GPU could be a testing nightmare.  Compute Shaders are DX only as you mentioned so I think a native plugin is the only other option for something like this.  In theory, you can wrap a call to a native plugin inside an update, execute calls to the GPU in some asynch fashion, and then pick up any results in the update on subsequent frames.  That seems totally hackish to me and may not even work.  Personally, I'd look for a different solution entirely that doesn't involve circumventing unity's abstraction over the hardware.

Comment: Thank you. It was really helpful information for me. Can I ask one more question? Someone recommend Unity OpenCL for GPGPU. Do you think it can be another option? Thank you.